# What protocol does iOS use to sync Notes to a server

Tags: icloud, notes.app

I was wondering which protocol the native application for notes on iOS is using to keep the data in sync with iCloud. My aim is to host the notes on my own server, but I could't figure out the protocol. Any help is much appreciated!
I would also be happy about tips on existing open source projects or a protocol specification as I will consider writing my own server application if I don't find any other software.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can host your own notes if you run an IMAP server. There are additional details in [knowledge base article HT4191](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4191). A great IMAP server is [Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. I will have a look at Dovecot.

Comment: Do you know if this still true in 2018??

Comment: @Todd That Knowledge Base article isn't at that URL anymore.  Are there search terms that might help me find it?

Comment: I'm trying to do this.  I've enabled "Notes" in the IMAP account on iOS, and the Notes app logged in to my IMAP server and created a Notes folder, but it's empty (looking from a desktop IMAP client).